# Converting XAML to bitmap in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to convert XAML to bitmap in Silverlight (I'm using version 4). I saw that there was a simple solution for WPF but the needed classes do not exist in Silverlight.

Has anyone done such a thing?

Comment: you mean you want to convert the source of an Image control to bitmap?

Comment: No, I'd like to take any control (like the entire canvas) and convert it to bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [WriteableBitmap.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render(v=VS.95).aspx). It takes a UIElement as argument which could be the root of the XAML tree that you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageTools library](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/).